# Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing - manually inserting pricing rules

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the [Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/), which is very useful but does not easily allow me to ammend pricing updates via. the database.

Looking at the sample data,

```
{"set_5339c459a78e7":
  {"conditions_type":"all",
   "conditions":{"1":{"type":"apply_to","args":{"applies_to":"everyone"}}},
   "collector":{"type":"product"},
   "mode":"block",
   "date_from":"",
   "date_to":"",
   "rules":{"1":{"from":"","to":"","type":"price_discount","amount":""}},
   "blockrules": {"1":{
     "from":"2",
     "adjust":"1",
     "type":"fixed_adjustment",
     "amount":"0.26","repeating":"yes"}}}}
```

it seems that the meta requires set_* to be specific with the product meta, or it will not apply correctly.

Revising the code, I notice this:

```
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hierarchical' => false, 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0));
foreach ($terms as $item_id => $item) {
            $set_index = $item->term_id;
            $name = 'set_' . $set_index;
}
```

This is bizarre to me, as the term_id appears to be a 13 character alphanumeric string than the expected bigint. Could anyone explain how I can reproduce this string for when I manually update my tables?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look through the code and I found that in `/admin/admin-init.php` where it specifies the AJAX handlers, this is how it comes up with new set names:

```
function woocommerce_pricing_product_admin_create_empty_ruleset() {
    global $wc_product_pricing_admin;
    $wc_product_pricing_admin->create_empty_ruleset( uniqid('set_') );
    die();
}
```

As you can see it just uses PHP's `uniqid` function prefixed by nothing but `"set_"` so in the case of product rules it appears to be just a random ID. 
Hope that helps.